# Problems with Kanji Font

Tags: discussion, kanji

I recently installed KDE Neon on my computer (Version 5.19.5), and I have come across some problems regarding my font settings. The font seems to be defaulting to chinese variants, as in, kanji like 刃 or 直 are being rendered as [image: 刃 variant] and [image: 直 variant]
, respectively. This persists unless the application forces a specific font type, like here in the JP Stack Exchange and Discord (when set to be in the japanese language).

I am still a beginner with Linux, and I am unfamiliar with how to configure the system to utilize the proper fonts. How should I proceed with this? (Also, do tell me if this is the proper site to ask this in. I was unsure as to where I should ask this in)

Comment: This should be moved to Meta

Comment: In Japanese stack exchange, these question tend to be migrated to meta, but might not receive enough attention this question deserves. It's in niche: https://unix.stackexchange.com would be best suited but perhaps it's too language-specific (east asian languages). Asking on https://ja.stackoverflow.com might be another good idea.

Comment: Does this help you? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Multilingual_support_(East_Asian)

Comment: @Yosh thanks for the pointer. Someone migrated the question already, but I'll make sure to keep that info in mind for the future.

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth unfortunately my computer is already installed with the necessary CJK fonts, japanese included. the problem seems to stem from how it is choosing said fonts for usage.

Comment: I think you can adapt this answer to prioritise Japanese: https://askubuntu.com/questions/901486/门-looks-weird-on-my-system-default-font

Comment: @dROOOze it did not quite work, for some reason. The `/etc/fonts/conf.d/64-language-selector-prefer.conf` file already has japanese as the main priority, and even changing ~/.fonts.conf didn't yield any results.